# Error When Connecting To Mongo Server Using IAM Role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoid, mongodb-atlas

I am using Mongoid gem in Rails with IAM session token to connect with my Atlas Cluster

```
 def logs
  reload_mongoid_configuration
  @logs ||= Log.or(attributes_condition)
               .where(selector)
               .order_by(timestamp: :desc)
end

 def reload_mongoid_configuration
  mongo_config = Mongoid::Config.clients[:default]
  old_connection_url = mongo_config[:uri]

  return unless mongo_token_expired?(old_connection_url)

  # Disconnect existing Mongoid clients
  Mongoid.disconnect_clients

  # Logic to get mongo URL with a new AWS session token
  Mongoid.load_configuration(
    clients: {
      default: {
        uri: MongoUriGenerator.audit_log_db_url(old_connection_url),
        options: {
          database: 'my_database'

        }
      }
    }
  )
end
```

As I am using an aws session token I need to regenerate the URL after 1 hour. It's working fine but after some time I am getting the following error

```
#<Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No primary server is available in cluster ...
#<Server address=<someaddress>.mongodb.net:27017 UNKNOWN NO-MONITORING pool=#<ConnectionPool size=0 (0-20) used=0 avail=0 pending=0 paused>> #<Server address=<someaddress>.mongodb.net:27017 SECONDARY replica_set=atlas-ihuqqp-shard-0 NO-MONITORING>]> with timeout=30, LT=0.015. The following servers have dead monitor threads
```

My connection url looks something like this

```
mongodb+srv://<temp_access key>:<temp_secret_key>@<mongourl>.mongodb.net/<db>?authMechanism=MONGODB-AWS&authSource=$external&authMechanismProperties=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN:IQo....
```

Comment: what's your connection string (other than creds)?

Comment: @dododo my connection url looks something like this `mongodb+srv://<temp_access key>:<temp_secret_key>@<mongourl>.mongodb.net/<db>?authMechanism=MONGODB-AWS&authSource=$external&authMechanismProperties=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN:IQo....`

Comment: the error says that you have no primary at this point. Only one secondary? It's unusual for atlas configuration. What's the state of atlas cluster?